# How to Fetch all the columns from the multiple tables by joining the tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to fetch all the column names from the database tables.If it is a single table I am able to do it using:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='nameofschema'
AND `TABLE_NAME`='tbl_name'
GROUP BY `COLUMN_NAME`
```

Now i need to get the column names from ten tables and show the columns names at one go.
How can I achieve this?
Please help me in this regrard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator like this

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='nameofschema'
AND `TABLE_NAME` IN ('tbl_name','tbl_name2','tbl_name3')
GROUP BY `COLUMN_NAME`
```

If tables are in different schemas , you can use combination of AND , OR opeartors

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA`='nameofschema' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'tbl_name')
       OR
      (`TABLE_SCHEMA`='nameofschema1' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'tbl_name1')
GROUP BY `COLUMN_NAME`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IN()`

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='dbname'
AND `TABLE_NAME` IN ('table1' ,'table2'.....)
GROUP BY `COLUMN_NAME`
```

Or to show all the columns from database

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='dbname'    
GROUP BY `COLUMN_NAME`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='nameofschema'
AND `TABLE_NAME` in ('tbl_name1','tbl_name2','tbl_name3')
GROUP BY `COLUMN_NAME`
```

Comment: And why is this one downvoted? Because of three and not ten tables?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

full details take a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp